# How to do a 'stripslashes' equivalent in BrightScript

Tags: roku, brightscript

I'm new to Roku and finding that my JSON feed response looks something like this:

```
http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/pd\/12345\/12345_1089831707001_test.mp4
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix the JSON response in BrightScript? I'm looking through the BrightScript reference document now, but just wanted to see if anyone knew of an easy way to do this while I continue to piece this together.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after a little more research I found the solution I needed.  Incase this helps anyone else, here's the function I wrote to fix the strings:

```
Function fixSlashes(item as string) As Object
r = "\\" 'backslash character

'case insensitive
 regexKeyFix = CreateObject( "roRegex", r, "i" )

    item = regexKeyFix.ReplaceAll( item, "" )
    Return item
End Function
```

And here's a link to the [documentation](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc42/roRegex) I found for this.

Comment: Might want to return a string instread of an object, function fixSlashes(item as string) as string

Comment: Thank you!  I thought of this after posting :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Replace` as a *simple* method

> Replace(from As String, to As String) As String
>
> Returns a copy of the string with all instances of fromStr replaced with toStr.  If fromStr is empty the return value is the same as the source string.

```
BrightScript Debugger> str = "http:\/\/brightcove.vo.llnwd.net\/e1\/pd\/12345\/12345_1089831707001_test.mp4"
BrightScript Debugger> ?item.Replace("\","")
http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/e1/pd/12345/12345_1089831707001_test.mp4
```

Comment: FWIW, these days one just needs to do `parseJSON()` on the above to get rid of the superfluous "\". There was some ridiculous reason these get added by PHP, i forgot what but it is not mandated by the JSON spec - rather was something related to browser security if string misused or such.